# Searching an unordered binary tree by key value

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I posted a question related to this topic earlier, but I'm having trouble figuring this out as well. I'm trying to search an unordered binary tree by a key value and return its associated value through a recursive function.

The class has the form:

```
  Class Node
  {
     private:
       Node *leftChild;
       Node *rightChild;
       int key;
       int value;
 }
```

With each variable having associated get methods. So I basically want to search through the binary tree and return its value once I get to the correct Node.

Here is my attempt thus far, I think I'm pretty close:

```
int preOrder(Node *node, int key)
{
   if(node->getKey() == key)
     return node->getValue();

  Node* leftNode = node->getLeft();

  if(leftNode != NULL)
  {
    return preOrder(leftNode, key);
  }

  Node* rightNode = node->getRight();

  if(rightNode != NULL)
  {
    return preOrder(rightNode, key);
  }

  //I know a return statement needs to be placed here
  //in case both pointers are NULL in order to return to the previous
  //node in the tree, but I'm not sure how to do this...
}
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Hang on, I'll dig out my class I wrote on your last question.

Comment: One piece of advice: use an ordered tree!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.  This includes the code to answer your last question, modified to support Key/Value nodes instead of just Value nodes.  Also, with the changes it made sense to return a pointer to the node rather than the value it contained, so I updated lowest to do it that way as well.

```
template <typename KeyT, typename ValueT>
class Node
{
public:
    Node(KeyT k, ValueT v)
    {
        key = k;
        value = v;
        right = NULL;
        left = NULL;
    }

    Node<KeyT, ValueT> * lowest()
    {
        Node<KeyT, ValueT> * v = this;

        if (right != NULL)
            if (v->value > left->value) v = left;
        if (left  != NULL)
            if (v->value > right->value) v = right;

        return v;
    }

    Node<KeyT, ValueT> * searchByKey(KeyT k)
    {
        if (key == k)
            return this;

        Node<KeyT, ValueT> * n = NULL;

        if (left != NULL)
            n = left->searchByKey(k);
        if (n != NULL) return n;
        if (right!= NULL)
            n = right->searchByKey(k);
        if (n != NULL) return n;

        return NULL;
    }

    Node<KeyT, ValueT> * getRight()
    {
        return right;
    }

    Node<KeyT, ValueT> * getLeft()
    {
        return left;
    }

    void setRight(Node<KeyT, ValueT> * nright)
    {
        right = nright;
    }

    void setLeft(Node<KeyT, ValueT> * nleft)
    {
        left = nleft;
    }

    KeyT getKey()
    {
        return key;
    }

    ValueT getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

private:
    KeyT   key;
    ValueT value;

    Node<KeyT, ValueT> * right;
    Node<KeyT, ValueT> * left;
};
```

Look at example output: http://ideone.com/l5ZNc

Comment: Wow yup this works perfectly for me. THanks so much for taking the time to do this. It's much easier to handle when generalizing to the Node type

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're close. You'll need to figure out what to return when you haven't found the key, because that's what's preventing you from finishing. Notice that if the left node isn't NULL that you'll never check the right node.

Comment: Yeah that's how a preOrder traversal works- it starts at the root and then traverses the left subtree before scanning the right subtree. So indeed the right subtree will not be visited until I'm done scanning the left. This where I'm stuck since I'm just having a problem back tracking to the previous Node once both child pointers are null.

Comment: @WakkaWakkaWakka, look at your original code again. You will *never* get to the right side once you've gone down the left.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int value=NULL;
    void preOrder(Node *node, int key)
    {
       if (node!=NULL){
          if(node->getKey() == key)
            value=node->getValue();

          preOrder(node->getLeft(),key);
          preOrder(node->getRight(),key); 
       }     
    }
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `break` in this context?

Comment: sorry..I was under the impression I'm iterating sth.. 10x

Comment: This is a void function.. I nee my function to return the value once we have reached the correct node. I see what you're doing with the global variable, however I need to do this for many many nodes, so isn't there a cleaner way of doing this?